Website on local machine doesn't run and redirects to phpmyadmin page
I took a full backup(including a partial backup of the 2 databases) of a site using Cpanel and downloaded it to my local machine and tried to run it using xampp
I have connected the databases and edited the wp-config files.
For one of the database in phpMyAdmin, I modified the options_value for option_name "site" to http://localhost/, and for option_name "home," I changed the options_value to http://localhost/site_name.
For the other database i modified the options_value to http://localhost/ for both option_name "site" and "home"
After this when i put localhost/site_name it redirects to the xampp phpmyadmin homepage
Things i have tried:

Check the redirects
Check the htaccess
Check Apache errorlog
Check httpd-vhosts.conf

